# Elasticsearch query in array conditions on doc fields

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "_index": "listings",
  "_type": "listing",
  "_id": "234",
  "_source": {
    "category_id": "43608",
    "categories": [
      43608,
      43596
    ]
  }
}
```

I wanna query to array search `category_id` in `categories`. some thing like that

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "category_id": "doc.categories"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

As, `category_id` is a string type, better to use `SHOULD` query instead of `MUST` and Simply, Itrate through the array `categories` and make separate `term` level query for each element in array.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category_id": "doc.categories[0]"
          }
        },
       {
          "term": {
            "category_id": "doc.categories[1]"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It will return you all which match any of `categories` array.

Comment: no you have to use script for find a field value in another field value,

Answer (score 0):

You have to user script for find a field value in another field value.

```
{
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "source": "doc.containsKey('categories') && doc['categories'].values.contains(doc['category_id'].value)",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
}
```